# Is there any alias available in Perl for referencing a module name?

Tags: perl

I have multiple Perl modules. The package names seems to be big

everytime i access the functions from those modules, i need to provide something like this

`&PackageName::Functionname()`

is there a shortcut or alias available in Perl which can reference the packages with bigger names

Thanks

Karthik

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the function without the `&`:

```
PackageName::Functionname();
```

Also there is the exporter mechanism which exports function from a module to your default namespace:

```
use PackageName 'Functionname';

Functionname();
```

For further explainations how to use `use` see http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html

How to export functions when writing your own modules, see http://perldoc.perl.org/Exporter.html

Comment: or you can specify which functions to be exported by default

Comment: You can _and should_ call the function without the `&`. The `&` prefix on function calls has non-obvious side effects which generally aren't going to be what you want.

Comment: If I call somethign like this `PackageName::Fucntion("param1","Param2")` I get a compilation error. If I call `&PackageName::Fucntion("param1","Param2")` works perfectly fine. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: @Karthik - I'll bet that `PackageName::Fucntion` was declared with a  *prototype* and that your function call is not consistent with that prototype, which is a compile time error. Calling a function with `&` disables the prototype check (this is just one of the non-obvious side effects that Dave Sherohman alluded to).

Comment: not it was not with prototype. just reading about Prototype. thanks for the info. Let me look into this

Comment: *[Karthik Krishnan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/309649/karthik-krishnan)*: It will be helpful (for us to help you) if you can let us know the error that was encountered.

Comment: This, addressing *functions*/routines, is not quite the solution (addressing a bit something different) to what the OP asked 'reference the *packages*' , you can use similarly use PackageName qw ( func1 func2 .. ) but it only references functions. By this approach you cannot reference the package, to eg instantiate it, eg like in the another answer in here.

Answer (score 10):

With [`Package::Alias`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Package::Alias) you can alias a long package name such as `Foo::Bar::Baz` to `baz`:

```
use Package::Alias 'baz' => 'Foo::Bar::Baz';

baz::quux;  # Invokes Foo::Bar::Baz::quux;
```

Comment: unfortunately i cannot use package::alias since i will be using RATLPERL